# How to change the color of TCylinder in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I can create a Cylinder

```
Img: TControl3D;
Img := TCylinder.Create(nil);
```

however Img does not seem to have a colour property. Even when I cast it as a cylinder. 
It seems to be defaulting to red. Also the object inspector does not have a colour property for cylinders either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each 3D shape object has **MaterialSource** property - use it to give your shape color/texture.

If you want to set shape material to solid colour, use **TColorMaterialSource** component, set color that you want, and link it to the shape's **MaterialSource** property.